# Передача переменной в less/sass

Tags: javascript, typescript, sass, less, angular

Как можно передать переменную из компонента `Angular` в препроцессор `less` или `sass`?

PS. или из `JavaScript`/`TypeScript`

Comment: нет............

Comment: никак нельзя?..

Comment: Сделать можно, но это не очень хорошая практика .... смотрите в сторону sass js и браузерных компиляторов.

Comment: Нет (если без встраивания компилятора), можно только в переменные CSS

Comment: Переменные CSS это как?

Comment: [Про css переменные](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)